# Bootstrap datepicker doesn't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have read that this bug was fixed but doesn't really seem so. I have a boostrap modal appearing when I create an new employee in my website. And I am using the following to create a datepicker for the date of birth of the new employee.

```
<div class="input-group date insertInfo" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and then after the load of my js scripts (first I load bootstrap and then bootstrap-datepicker.js) I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately what happens is that I can select the date on the drop down calendar shown by the datepicker, but once selected I cannot close it anymore. Can you maybe help me with this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do the following:

1. Correct your class reference
2. Enable autoclose
3. Override button

When you setup the datepicker, you are referencing a non-existant class ('.datepicker'). Besides that, you need to include the 'autoclose' field and customize the behaviour of the button to make it both open and close the calendar.

HTML

```
<div class="input-group date insertInfo" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-addon close-button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
// Setup datepicker

$('.date').datepicker({
  format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
  autoclose: true
});

// Unbind default events

$('.close-button').unbind();

// Specify new behaviour

$('.close-button').click(function() {
  if ($('.datepicker').is(":visible")) {
    $('.date').datepicker('hide');
  } else {
    $('.date').datepicker('show');
  }
});
```

If you want to see a working version: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r_costa/qgzwwt70/)

Comment: but I reached the same behaviour. The question is: does it close by clicking on the calendar icon?

Comment: Do you want the icon to work as a toggle button to open and close the calendar ?

Comment: I do.. and I thought that was the normal behavior. It opens the calendar and I thought that it was supposed to close it as well..

Comment: I´ve already updated my answer to achieve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

After selecting the date from the drop down calendar you can just click anywhere outside the calendar to close it but if you want the calendar to be closed on selecting the date then do the following

```
   $(function () {
            $('.date').datepicker({
                format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
                autoclose: true
            })
        });
```

Comment: and that is right indeed! the last missing thing is that it doesn't close when I click on the icon of the calendar.. so that markup gives a field where the date will be written once selected, and the icon of the calendar right close to it. I can select the date by clicking on the field or the icon of the calendar. If I select the date, the calendar closes correctly. But if I click again on the calendar icon, the calendar doesn't close. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        autoclose: true
    });
```

You will need to EXPLICITLY add autoclose: true, otherwise, its default value is false.

Comment: My gosh, I wish they have told this in the DOC. how many hours wasted scouring the events. Thanks a bunch sire. God bless you

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap datepicker has *autoclose* option set on *false* by default.
You should set *autoclose* option on *true*.

Check out the reference: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#quick-reference

Comment: doesn't really work.. maybe a code snippet on http://codepen.io/pen/ would help? Thanks in advance!!